# Stuck in error JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string

Tags: java, php, json, react-native

I am stuck in very common error JSON parse error cannot figure out web service is faulty or fetch code I get a response from this web service when I test it in my postman it return two objects but when I want to login from this web service it always gives parse error
[image: Error ScreenShot]

[image: PostMan response from RAW INPUT]

React Native Function to loginUser where may be error is present

```js
UserLoginFunction = () =>{
 const { UserContact }  = this.state ;
 const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;
 if(this.state.UserContact == ""){
   ToastAndroid.show('Pleas Enter Contact Number Correctly ',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
 }
 else if (this.state.UserPassword == ""){
   ToastAndroid.show('Please Enter Password Correctly',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
 }
 else{

fetch(urls.localhosturl + urls.login, { 
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
 
    user_contact: UserContact,
    user_password: UserPassword,
    //user_name: UserName,
 
  })
 
})
      
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        console.log(responseJson)
        // If server response message same as Data Matched
         if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
          {
            //Save User Details to Local Storage
            AsyncStorage.setItem("userContact", JSON.stringify(UserContact));
            //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{user_contact:UserContact,});

        }
        else{
          ToastAndroid.show(responseJson,ToastAndroid.SHORT);
          //Alert.alert(string,responseJson);
          
        }

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
 
    }
  }
```

PHP webservice

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<?php

// Importing DBConfig.php file.
include 'config.php';
// Creating connection.
$con = mysqli_connect($host_name, $host_user, $host_password, $database_name);
// Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$user_contact = $obj['user_contact'];
$user_password = $obj['user_password'];

// $user_contact = $_REQUEST['user_contact'];
// $user_password = $_REQUEST['user_password'];
//$user_name = $obj['user_name'];

$Sql_Query = "select * from user_information where user_contact = '$user_contact' and user_password = '$user_password' ";
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $Sql_Query));

if (isset($check)) {
    $SuccessLoginMsg = 'Data Matched';
    // Converting the message into JSON format.
    $SuccessLoginJson = json_encode($SuccessLoginMsg);
    // Echo the message.
    echo $SuccessLoginJson;
} else {
    // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
    $InvalidMSG = 'Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again';
    // Converting the message into JSON format.
    $InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);
    // Echo the message.
    echo $InvalidMSGJSon;
}

$result = $con->query($Sql_Query);
$array = $result->fetch_assoc();
$json = json_encode($array, true);

echo $json;

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: The "Data Matched" is breaking the json, looks like someone left some debug code in. Woopsy! Service appears to be at fault.

Comment: @rjdown what's the solution

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the standard output of your PHP service is used as the source of the JSON.

In that case, the fact that you are spitting out the following line is causing you trouble:

```
echo $SuccessLoginJson;
```

You may want to either suppress this message, write it to a log file, or perhaps write it to standard error instead.  In any case, you've turned your web service into something that gives your client two results instead of one, and the client doesn't understand how to handle it.